# how to insert multiple checked items to mysql table?

Tags: php, html, checkboxlist

im working on an e-shop project i have some problem in adding a new product.
this involve three tables:

- products:               p_id, name, price
- attribute :             a_id, name (attributes of a product e.g color , brand etc)
- product_attribute :     id, p_id, a_id, value, 
                      (value here is e.g. white for attribute color)

to add a new product my html form display:
1. text fields for its name and price
2. a check-box list that displays all attribute along with text fields to enter its value.

but im confused how to insert this information in database.

here is the code:

```
           $qry = "select att_name from attribute";
           $res = mysql_query($qry);
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
         {
           ?>

                <tr>
               <td width="136" nowrap="nowrap" class="gridLabels1">
               <input type="checkbox" name="chk_group[]" value='$row' /><?php echo $row['att_name'];?> <br /></td> // checkbox list of all attributes
               <td width="740" class="gridValue1">
               <input name="value" type="text" class="inputText" id="value" size="29"/> </td> // text fields to enter value
           </tr>
           <?php
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: first step in inserting data to database would be to have an INSERT statement. Second, you should specify what db you use. Third, check this question, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081360/php-how-can-i-insert-multiple-items-from-a-shopping-cart-into-the-database?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

First i will suggest you that use the id of the attribute in to the value of the checkbox.

You can user [implode](http://php.net/implode) function to insert the attributes in database and the values will explode by comma separated.

As you have defined the array than use the implode like :
suppose your array values :

```
$all_atributes=implode(",",$_POST['chk_group']);
$all_atributes//will output selected ids id1,id4,id5
```

And use this $all_atributes to insert into the database.

Comment: i should separately list all attributes with value = their id?

Comment: in check box you are showing the name of the attribute and send the id of the attribute in value when you post it.

Comment: if user adds a new product e.g
name laptop price 123
and check the brand attribute for it and fill 'dell' in the text field in front it.
how do i insert this data in my table product_attribute??

Comment: your product_attribute should have already filled with the names of the attribute and when user enters the product than the list of all arrtibutes should come over there with checkbox.